# Flash AS3, How to pause a loop for seconds

Tags: loops, actionscript-3, flash

I have this AS3 script (it works fine), I just want to make the loop to pause for seconds each time then it can continue looping. Like if I like it to stop for Milliseconds.Thanks

```js
var myText:String; 
var counter:int = 0; 

var format : TextFormat = new TextFormat();
format.size = 16;
format.font = "Verdana";
format.bold = true;
format.color = 0x000000; 

var textField : TextField = new TextField();
textField.width = 200;
textField.height = 50;
textField.selectable = false;
textField.wordWrap = true;
textField.defaultTextFormat = format;
textField.x = textField.y =0;
addChild(textField);
    
var textLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest("text.txt"));
textLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function(e:Event){initText(e.target.data);});

function initText(string:String):void{
 myText = string; 
 addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, writeText); 
}

function writeText(e:Event):void{
 if (counter <= myText.length){
         textField.text = myText.substr(0,counter); 
         counter++;
         /*What I can put here to make it pause for a while*/
 }
 else{
  removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,writeText); 
 }
}
```

Comment: You can have a look at the [Timer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html#includeExamplesSummary) class. Try using that instead of ENTER_FRAME to control the delay between text updates

Comment: Cut the function into two and add a listener for `ENTER_FRAME` for `root` to run the second part later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine, you need to tweak it a little bit.

```
function initText(string:String):void
{
    myText = string; 
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, writeText); 
}

// Variable to keep the next print time in milliseconds.
var nextPrint:int;

function writeText(e:Event):void
{
    // Function getTimer() returns time in milliseconds since app start.
    // Skip this frame if time is not right.
    if (getTimer() < nextPrint) return;

    // Variable nextPrint is initially 0 so the first char will print immediately.

    if (counter <= myText.length)
    {
        textField.text = myText.substr(0, counter); 
        counter++;

        /*What I can put here to make it pause for a while*/
        // Print next character in ~100 ms.
        nextPrint = getTimer() + 100;
    }
    else
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, writeText); 
    }
}
```